# Resolution on my VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 guest can be a max of 1280 X 664 (I have Guest Additions installed)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I have a Windows 10 laptop running Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.22.  I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a virtual environment and installed Guest Additions (I can copy/paste to/from Ubuntu to/from Windows, so I know it works).

If I increase the resolution from 1280 X 664 on the Ubuntu VM, the desktop goes off the screen (I can no longer see the launcher icon in the lower left corner).  I have tried enabling 3D Acceleration, but the screen then becomes too small.

I have a Dell laptop with a resolution of 3840 X 2160, so I should be able to come close to that.  It has an Intel HD Graphics 350 card.  I have tried the different graphics drivers in the Ubuntu image, but none seem to make a difference.

*More Information:*

I installed VB on another (desktop) and created a VM from the same iso.  I was able to get a resolution of 2560 X 1495 without any issues.  The other machine is an AMD FX-8150, the laptop giving me issues is an Intel I7 (much newer).  The desktop has an AMD Radeon R5 video card.
I copied that VM folder to my laptop and only got the aforementioned resolution.  IMHO, There is something wacky going on with the Intel video drivers.

Comment: Are you running the VirtualBox in a window? If so, have you  tried resizing the window?

Comment: yes. I have tried full-screen and scaled.  I have tried auto-resizing the guest display.  I have tried rebooting after each change.  The only glimmer of hope I have is when I enable 3D acceleration in the VB Display settings.  It appears to give me the resolution I request, but the client screen only takes up about 1/10 of the host screen (in the upper-left corner) and the mouse does not track properly in the guest window.

Comment: No suggestions?

Comment: Still no suggestions?